# Larave darkaonline/l5-swagger OpenApi Execute Button Not Working with Array Parameter

Tags: laravel, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm currently working on integrating Swagger UI into my project, and I've encountered an issue with the "Execute" button not working as expected when using the 'field[]' array parameter.
but when removing the '[]' it does work
Here's the problem I'm facing:

[The field in swagger ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwHxg.png)

```
@OA\Property(property="tags[]", type="array", @OA\Items(type="integer", example=1), description="Array of tag IDs associated with the property"),
```

I am using

```
"darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^8.5"
```

> **note: there are no errors shown in the console**

1. I tried upgrading assets versions
2. removed package and installed it again